# Figure includes unknown/excess text

Tags: floats

I am using a custom figure command defined in my `.sty` to show figures:
`\def\thefigure{\@arabic\c@figure}`

I then make a figure as:

```
\begin{thefigure}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{test}
   \captionof{figure}{test image}
   \label{fig:test1}
\end{thefigure}
```

But when I go to show a figure there is extra text, a random zero, before my caption. Here is an example:

[image]

No errors are thrown in generating the pdf.

Comment: Why not just use `\begin{center}
   \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
   \captionof{figure}{test image}
   \label{fig:test1}
\end{center}` instead?

Comment: That worked thanks. Are there any downsides to using `\begin{center}`? Like numbering issues over several chapters or any other quirks?

Comment: `\thezzzz` is a standard latex command for the print form of the counter zzzz  so `\def\thefigure{\@arabic\c@figure}` is perfectly standard and specifies the figure counter should use arabic numbers (this is actually te default). But then using this as `\begin{thefigure}`  is completely wrong and will just cause that number to be typeset.

Comment: The 0 is not "random" you are typesetting `\thefigure` which is 0 until the first caption increments it to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstood the intention of the class declaration

```
\def\thefigure{\@arabic\c@figure}
```

every LaTeX counter has a `\the....` command that defines its print form, and here you are declaring that the `figure` counter should use 1,2,3... rather than say `\@alph` which would cause it to use a,b,c,...

While you can use `\thefigure` directly that is rather rare, but this form is used in `\caption` and other places whenever the figure number is needed.

```
\begin{thefigure}
\includegraphics{zzz}
\end{thefigure}
```

is equivalent to

```
{\thefigure
\includegraphics{zzz}
}
```

so it typesets the current value of the counter (which is 0 before the first caption increments it) followed by the figure. Which is why you see a 0 to the left of your image, on its baseline (although it looks slightly below it due to white space in the image).

The normal forms would be

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{...}
\caption{...}
\end{figure}
```

or if for some reason you do not want to allow floating

```
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics{...}
    \captionof{figure}{...}
\end{center}
```

In either case the `\thefigure` definition will affect the typesetting of the figure number in the caption.

Comment: Thanks I think this also explains why when i put a `\caption` in `\thefigure` it throws an error as well.

Comment: @guy yes you can (by default) only use `\caption` in floats, so in the `figure` environment here. You should use `figure` unless you are sure you should not use it.